# std::scoped_lock and mutex ordering

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17, locking, deadlock

I'm trying to determine if [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) tries to establish an ordering or mutex id to acquire locks in a prescribed order. Is not clear to me that it does it from a somewhat brief looking at a [browsable implementation I found googling around](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex).

In case it is not doing that, What would be the closest to standard implementation of acquiring an ordered set of locks?

Typically the cleanest way to avoid deadlocks is to always acquire a group of locks in the same order (and yes, sure, always release them all before trying to acquire new locks again, but perhaps 2PL is a little beyond the scope of what `std::scoped_lock` should aim to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order for `std::lock` isn't defined until run-time, and it is not fixed.  It is discovered experimentally by the algorithm for each individual call to `std::lock`.  The second call to `std::lock` could lock the mutexes in a different order than the first, even though both calls might use the same list of mutexes in the same order at the call site.

Here is a detailed performance analysis of several possible implementations of `std::lock`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Using a fixed ordering of the mutexes is one of the algorithms that is performance-compared in the above link.  It is not the best performing algorithm for the experiments conducted.

The [libstdc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex) the OP points to is a high quality implementation of what [the analysis](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) labels "Smart & Polite"

Comment: I am tempted to make a different test where I believe the ordered strategy should win (or at least not lose significantly), under a distribution of locks that is more spread  (which would be the case for, say, a range-based locking of an index or a table) and with less contemption of a small subset of lower locks. If I do it I'll ping you on your blog

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I suspect you are correct that such an experiment will show much less of difference between the algorithms.  The analysis aimed to highlight the differences between the algorithms.  The **Problem Description** section contains this quote:  "If the scenario is low-contention, the algorithm does not matter, as long as it avoids deadlock."

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the examples. So the `unique_lock` should release at destructor, but why you explicitly call `release` on the 1st `unique_lock` on the S&P `::lock`? also why the need to call them explicitly in the ordered `::lock`? does that matter?

Comment: Prior to `u0.release()`, the mutex referenced by `l0` is owned both by the argument `l0`, and the local `unique_lock`, `u0`.  `u0.release()` transfers unique ownership to `l0` just before the algorithm successfully returns.  If `l1.try_lock()` would have resulted in an exception, then the destruction of the local `u0` would unlock `l0` as the exception propagates out, leaving all mutexes unlocked.

Comment: In other words, the local `unique_lock`s are nothing more than your standard RAII devices for exception safety.  If no exception is thrown, then they release their ownership, leaving the by-reference argument list as the only owners.

Comment: what is the difference between doing `unique_lock(l0); try_lock(l1, l2)` and doing the simple thing `try_lock(l0, l1, l2)`? or more precisely, why the latter seems to take so much more time than the former?

Comment: I'm not sure why the latter would take more time than the former (I haven't measured that).  The difference is that `try_lock` never blocks.  It will return immediately and the return value will indicate if all locks were obtained, and if not, which lock in the list failed.  The former unconditionally locks `l0`, and will block until it succeeds in obtaining that lock.

Comment: ok I was confused because I hadn't understood the `unique_lock` documentation correctly, I was assuming `release` unlocks, instead it is just "giving up ownership". I wasn't aware of that, now it makes much more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`scoped_lock`'s constructor is stated to call `std::lock` on its mutexes, so its behavior is governed by this function. And [`std::lock` is specifically defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) to avoid deadlocks on what it locks. The order it locks the mutexes in is undefined, but it won't result in a deadlock.

Comment: are you saying the mutex order is 1) undefined but fixed at compile-time 2) that it is undefined at run-time but fixed for the lifetime of the process or that 3) it avoid deadlocks even when locks are acquired in different order?

Comment: It's undefined, but it won't result in a deadlock. That's it. How exactly an implementation implements it is up to the implementation. But since `lock` isn't `constexpr`, there can't be a compile-time fixed anything.